# Struts 2 Default Page

Tags: java, url, struts2, home-directory, welcome-file

I have a a web application using struts two that can access a action by literally typing it into the URL

```
localhost/project/index.action
```

but it won't redirect to this default action without explicitly typing it in.

```
localhost/project/
```

gives the error

```
Error 404: SRVE0190E: File not found: {0}
```

I am assuming the file isn't found because I don't have something configured correctly.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as for getting this behavior with Struts 2?

Per request here is my struts.xml and web.xml

web.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
<display-name>Doc Parser</display-name>

<filter>
    <filter-name>struts-prepare</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts-execute</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts-prepare</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/struts/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/struts/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts-execute</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/struts/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.listener.StrutsListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>sitemesh-freemarker</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.struts2.sitemesh.FreemarkerDecoratorServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>default_encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>sitemesh-velocity</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.struts2.sitemesh.VelocityDecoratorServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>default_encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>


<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>sitemesh-freemarker</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.ftl</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>sitemesh-velocity</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.vm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Strust.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.1.7//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.1.7.dtd">
```

```xml
<constant name="struts.freemarker.templatesCache" value="true" />

<constant name="site.framework.roles"
    value="
    free => http://security.site.com/service/mwstutorial/getItems,
    loggedIn => http://security.site.com/service/mwstutorial/setItems" />

<package name="blank" extends="default">

</package>
```

Comment: This can be achieved by working on web.xml and / or struts.xml. Show both your files to get a better help

Comment: just added them,  I was wondering if it might have something to do with the <welcome-file-list> tag?

Comment: Are you using annotations?

Comment: Try to add a convention plugin it will handle such situation.

Comment: yes i am using struts conventions already

Comment: @Results({
  @Result(name = "success", location="index.jsp")
})
@Action("index")

Comment: that the annotations i used for my index action

Comment: Did you try to remove welcome-file list?

Comment: I did.  It didn't work but gave me a different error NoTargetForURIException: No target servlet configured for uri: /project/

Comment: Which one (a different error)? Did you use `@ResultPath` or where your jsps are?

Comment: I did not use @ResultPath and the error is listed in my previous comment.  I didn't give it any other welcome file location such as where my jsps are i simply removed it to see what would happen.

Comment: I shouldn't need to use '@ResultPath' though because I change the locaiton of my jsps in the struts.xml file  (i.e  <constant name="struts.convention.result.path" value="/pages/" />
)

Comment: What happened? Your struts filter isn't mapped to a folder location and uses an action extension for actions. What would be better to use a default action or index action if map to the folder location. The convention plugin should handle it. Why don't you map a struts filter to  `/*`?

Comment: Nothing happened.  I got the NoTargetForURIException.  What do you mean by my struts filter isn't mapped to a folder location?

Comment: Oh I see what you mean! Thanks.  i used a url-pattern of /*.  I will post an answer for others.

Comment: @9er Check if it works first.

Comment: it does indeed work :) Thanks @RomanC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a slightly different approach. And it does not matter if it is Struts 2 or even java.

Just add an index.html in the root of your web application that does a redirect.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url="http://localhost/home.action" />
```

Alternately, you can use javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            window.location.href = "http://localhost/home.action"
        </script>
```

That way you don't need to worry about welcome files as well as struts.xml configuration. Plus you can use this approach in other applications too.

Answer (score 2):

I found that the filter mappings of

```
    <url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/struts/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
```

were preventing the redirect to my welcome file.

the pattern of

```
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
```

fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

For action as defaut page this works for me

```
<welcome-file-list>     
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/index.jsp</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

index.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<s:action name="welcome21" namespace="/" executeResult="true" />
```

struts.xml (jsp result not tiles)

```
<package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
        <result-types>
            <result-type name="tiles"
                class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult" />
        </result-types>


        <action name="welcome21" class="org.zzz.action.CommonAction" method="welcome">
            <result>/jsp/welcome2.jsp</result>          
        </action>
```